# How to abstract libraries to dll and get no include errors?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17

I have executable target `sandbox` that depends on target `library`(shared library).
`library` depends on `spdlog`(PRIVATELY, so `sandbox` does not recieve any `spdlog` include directories). `spdlog` is static library.

In `library` target header file I include some `spdlog` headers:
`#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>`. This target compiles and links successfully.

But when compiling `sandbox` target i recieve error:
`fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'spdlog/spdlog.h': No such file or directory`.
And it's pretty reasonable! `sandbox` target doesn't have any `spdlog` include directories so the file won't be found!

So here's the question: what should i do to avoid this problem if I want `sandbox` target only depend on my `library`?

P.S.
I really had no idea how to name this problem.

---

P.P.S
Here's some code:

```
// in sandbox.cpp
#include <library/header.hpp>
// ...
```

```
// in library/header.hpp
// Compiles successfully during library build
// Throws include error when compiling sandbox.cpp
#include <spdlog/spdlog.h>
// ...
```

Comment: It looks like sandbox depends on spdlog.

Comment: That's the problem!
In CMake i have: target_link_libraries(library **PRIVATE** spdlog)

Comment: Specifying PRIVATE there does not prevent sandbox from depending on spdlog. cmake in general does not verify or enforce correctness of specified dependencies. That's directive for linker btw. You should fix your code instead. Make sure that spdlog headers are not exposed to sandbox, directly or indirectly

Comment: I understand! How can I do it?
I want to have single DLL(library) with all needed libraries(like spdlog) linked in here statically. And then link this single DLL to sandbox. But headers have that include problem=\

Comment: The question is why do you want to not depend on spdlog. Maybe that can shine some light on the problem.

Comment: That's like the problem i want to solve!
I think it's great design idea to abstract libraries into my API(create wrapper classes).
Then i can switch from spdlog and client app(sandbox) will see no changes.
Sandbox doesn't need to know what library depends on.

Comment: well, editing cmake won't lead to anywhere. You should fix hierarchy of header files.

Comment: if there's no solution or just it'll be better to make sandbox link to spdlog - I'll do that.

Comment: there is a solution, it just does not involve cmake...

Comment: So hierarchy is the only way? Because I think at some point It will be impossible to make such hierarchy without errors.

Comment: You can't have the cake and eat it in the same time. If dependency is private, it means, you can not depend on it in any interface files. And if you include dependency in header file, the dependency is no longer private.

Comment: @SergeyA okay, thanks for clarifying this. I thought that somehow it's possible to avoid this(

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you want `spdlog` to be internal for you library, include its headers in .c/.cpp files only. This way, users of your library will be completely separated from `spdlog` stuff.

Comment: @arrowd thanks, understood